# Keep tracking foreground service alive even if the app is killed

Tags: android, service, kill-process, foreground-service

I'm developing an app where i need to track the users via GPS. I'm using a service to control the position but when i close the app and i kill it, the service stops. I've tried to connect the service with a notification bar but the problem persists. I've tried a lot of solutions that i've read in several posts but i cant keep it alive as i need. My intention is to keep the service running all the time, even when the app is killed. I don't know if this is possible.

In the mainActivity i'm starting the service:

```
 private void iniciarServicioGPS() {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        startService(service);
}
```

LocationService.class:

```
 public class LocationService extends Service {
 Intent intent;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("GPS", "onCreate");
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void start (Intent intent, int startId){
    Log.i("GPS", "onStart antes location manager");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();        
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
}

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("gps", "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.amu_bubble_mask);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("ELE")
            .setTicker("ELE")
            .setContentText("Servicio de tracking activo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.amu_bubble_mask)
            .setLargeIcon(
                    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    startForeground(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT,notification);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I kill it"? Is it a closing of all activities, removing app from recents list, performing "force stop" from settings, or something else?

Comment: If i close all the activities, the service keeps working without the help of the notification. I refer killing the app by removing it from the app recent list @Sergio

Comment: So, do you see status bar "Servicio de tracking activo" notification after swiping app out of recents?

Comment: No, i don't see it. The status bar is gone when i swipe it

Comment: Really strange. Since once `startForeground()` was called, the associated notification shouldn't disappear even after manipulations with recents list. Do you call to `stopForeground()` somewhere? Also did you check this behavior on alternative device?

Comment: stopForeground() is not called in the app. I've tried with other phones and i get the same result